# Error Handling An Entire Class

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, try-catch

I've inherited a Winforms program that uses some 3rd party software, for which I cannot see the source code.  When calling the methods in this code, it is expected to connect to a reader, which the software checks for.  Unfortunately, the connection seems to drop from time to time, and the hidden functions cause the program to fail silently.  Is there a way to handle every call to this class' methods without using a try catch on every one?

The software looks something like this, with the Reader class being used such that we can access the same reader across multiple modules:

```
public class Reader
{
   private ThirdPartyReader thirdPartyReader;

   public ObjectReport QueryObjects()
   {
      return thirdPartyReader.QueryObjects();
   }

   public Settings QuerySettings()
   {
      return thirdPartyReader.QuerySettings();
   }
}
```

Comment: When you say : "When calling the methods in this code" I am assuming you are uding DLLs from 3rd party, if so you can use IL Disassembler to see whats going on inside - ofcourse this does not solve your overall problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Winforms.  I wasn't sure if that was relevant to the issue.

Basically, what I'm considering to this point is either try catching the calls to this class, or building a wrapper with a try catch built in. I was hoping that there was an approach I hadn't heard of.

Comment: Did you want to just ignore the exceptions? If you absorb every exception, how will you know what went wrong?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie It's a hardware issue that we're aware of.  I just need to log and show an error message before it crashes, and I don't want to throw in a bunch of try-catches if there's a simpler way.

Comment: If it's a guaranteed crash for your application, you could always subscribe to [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and do your logging from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static TResult Try<TObject, TResult>(this TObject source, Func<TObject, TResult> method, string message = null)
        {
            try
            {
                return method(source);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Some Logging or whatever, optionally using the message parameter;
                return default(TResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
        var reader = new ThirdPartyReader();
        var objects = reader.Try(x => x.QueryObjects());
        var settings = reader.Try(x => x.QuerySettings(), "Error Reading Settings");
```

It's really not that different because you still have to do reader.Try(), instead of just calling methods, but it's a much abbreviated syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is pretty similar to the wrapper that I have.  I'll mark this as the answer if it turns out to be the best solution.